# How to display a web page in a local app using Go

Tags: go, webview

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to display a web page in my local aplication, for example, show Google Map.
This using the go language and if it is necessary external libraries or frameworks.

I try us the librarie of webwiew:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/webview/webview"
)

func main() {
    w := webview.New(false)
    defer w.Destroy()
    w.SetTitle("Mi primera aplicación con webview")
    w.SetSize(800, 600, webview.HintNone)
    w.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
    w.Run()
}
```

I get the librarie usin "go get github.com/webview/webview", but when i run the code Shows this: `no required module provides package github.com/webview/webview; to add it`

help me please

Comment: You should be clear about a language's basics if you intend to write an app in it. The error message actually tells you what you need to do, you cut of your quote exactly at that: _"to add it..."_

Comment: i ran the code and got the same error too

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the whole error message "add it: go get github.com/webview/webview" run the coman and continue the same problem

Comment: @diomersandoval do yourself a favor and use Go Modules; then instead of `go get this` and `go get that` you can just `go mod tidy`.  Looking at github.com/webview/webview I suspect you should be importing [github.com/webview/webview_go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/webview/webview_go#readme-getting-started)